# Query on parent's collection - Hibernate Specification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have three tables created with Hibernate. **Product** is the parent while **barcodes** is a collection end **price** is a child (one to many) of products.

```
@NotBlank
private String ref;    

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "products_barcodes")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<String> barcodes;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<PriceEntity> prices;
```

I'm trying to query starting from the child (Price). I was able to query on a string but now i would like to query on the collection s element.

```
     Specifications<PriceEntity> specifications = where(hasTenant(tid));

     if (isNotBlank(ref)) {
         specifications = specifications.and(hasRef(ref));
     }

     if (isNotBlank(barcode)) {
         specifications = specifications.and(hasBarcode(barcode));
     }


     /*********************************/


    public static Specification<PriceEntity> hasRef(final String ref) {

        return new Specification<PriceEntity>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<PriceEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

                return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<PriceEntity>get("parent").get("ref"), ref);
            }
        };
    }

public static Specification<PriceEntity> hasBarcode(final String barcode) {

    return new Specification<PriceEntity>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<PriceEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<PriceEntity>get("parent").get("barcodes"), barcode);
        }
    };
}
```

how would you write the specification? The one above is not working, i get this exception at runtime:

```
"IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [8003921360408] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]"
```

Thanks

Comment: Define "not working". Does it fail to compile? Does it throw exceptions at runtime? Does is just return the wrong results?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for pointing that out. I 've updated the question.

Comment: `criteriaBuilder.equal(...)` wouldn't work with a collection and a value. I haven't used criteria query in a while but you should have a look at `isMember()`, e.g. `criteriaBuilder.isMember(barcode, root.<PriceEntity>get("parent").get("barcodes"))`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas . 
Your answer solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved by Thomas s comment.

For collections `criteriaBuilder.isMember` should be used.